# Set PDF tags while converting images to PDF with ImageMagick

Tags: shell-script, command-line, pdf, conversion, imagemagick

I'm converting images to a single PDF-file using `convert` utility:

```
$ convert "document-*.tiff" -compress jpeg -quality 60 "output.pdf"
```

Resulting document has the following tags set up:

```
Title:          output
Producer:       file:///usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/html/index.html
CreationDate:   Fri May 21 19:12:24 2021 +04
ModDate:        Fri May 21 19:12:24 2021 +04
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      419.52 x 595.2 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      226476 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3
```

Is it possible to override default values for tags like Title and Producer?

Comment: Does it need to be done by imagemagick or are you also interested in solutions using another tool to change the tag in the generated pdf?

Comment: @terdon If possible I would like to set tags during conversion, because as I understand from ExifTool documentation all subsequent modifications will be reversible and old versions of tags will stay in a PDF file.

Comment: Anything you do will be reversible. That's just meta data and any editor that can handle PDF tags can change the values. Why is that a problem?

Comment: Which version of imagemagick are you using? `convert --version`. The `Producer` tag [was a bug](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/1063), but has been fixed a couple of years ago.

Comment: @terdon I meant that `exiftool` will only append new version of tags (not actually overriding old values, they will stay in file itself). So you can restore original values by deleting changes like `$ exiftool -PDF-update:all= file.pdf`.

Comment: OK. So the solution is to not use `exiftool`, right?

Comment: @terdon, Yes, either set up tags via IM itself or after conversion via anything that will erase old tags.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, I'm using v6.9.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it. You need to change the image registry with a [`-define`](https://imagemagick.org/script/defines.php)

For example:

```
$ magick -compress jpeg -quality 60 -define pdf:Producer="Stackoverflow" -define pdf:Title="Change tags" "*tiff" "output.pdf"

$ pdfinfo output.pdf 
Title:          Change tags
Author:         https://imagemagick.org
Producer:       Stackoverflow
CreationDate:   Fri May 21 10:49:33 2021 -03
ModDate:        Fri May 21 10:49:33 2021 -03
Tagged:         no
[...]
```

But for that you need at least version 7 (that's why I asked you in the comments). If you don't have it, you can build it yourself, it is surprisingly simple.

For Debian 10, where I just tested, you need to:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ cd /some/path
$ wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
$ cd ImageMagick-7.0.11-13 # that's today's, the version might change
$ ./configure
$ make
```

You don't need to do a system-wide install. Just run the command like this:

```
$ /some/path/ImageMagick-7.0.11-13/utilities/magick -compress jpeg -quality 60 -define pdf:Producer="Stackoverflow" -define pdf:Title="Change tags" "*tiff" "output.pdf"
```

Comment: There is also portable version available on IM site: https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#linux, which you could just download and use.